# A faster or more efficent way to find the last .bmp resource id in a PE file

Tags: c++, winapi

Is there a faster or more efficent way to get the last bmp resource id in a PE file? I have 30 + PE files some with 1000's of bmp reosurces. They are loaded when the program gets launched it takes about 1-2 minutes to load all the PE files.

```
unsigned int Video::CountResources(HMODULE module,unsigned int maxid)
{
    if(maxid > 9999) maxid = 9999;//hardcode value for now

    if(!module)return 0;

    BITMAP bm;
    HBITMAP bitmap = 0;
    unsigned int last_id = 0;

    for(unsigned int resid = 0; resid <= maxid; ++resid)
    {
        if (bitmap) DeleteObject(bitmap);

        bitmap = LoadBitmap( module, MAKEINTRESOURCE( 101+resid ) );
        if (!bitmap) continue;

        if(!GetObject(bitmap,sizeof(bm),reinterpret_cast<LPSTR(&bm))) continue;

        last_id = resid;
    }
    return last_id+1;
}
```

Problem solved! I tried EnumResourceNames() a few other methods and a couple pe_libs. The bottom line is all functions to count resources iterate through the resource file 1 loop to another there is not much improvemnt in speed so I just modified my CountResources() function to use FindResource instead of LoadBimap and am satisfied with the result. **The actual problem was a little deeper in my code where I checked for existence of a preloaded module and if it didnt exist the module called LoadLibrary() which the preloaded module did not exist every time.** My current loadtime for all PE files is 4 seconds. Thankyou all for your help and input!

```
unsigned int Video::CountResources(HMODULE module,unsigned int maxid)
{
    //hardcode value for now
    if(maxid > 9999) maxid = 9999;

    if(!module) return 0;

    unsigned int last_id = 0;
    HRSRC hRes;

    for(unsigned int resid = 0; resid <= maxid; ++resid)
    {
        hRes = FindResource(module, MAKEINTRESOURCE(101+resid ),RT_BITMAP);

        if (!hRes) continue;

        last_id = resid;
    }

    return last_id+1;
}
```

Comment: I would think a loop based on `FindResource` rather than `LoadBitmap` would be faster. I cannot verify that, as I do not have a windows box in front of me, but probably worth a try.

Comment: There are various function to enumerate resources have a look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648008(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Creating_a_Resource_List and also search "msdn enumerate resources"

Comment: The title suggests you want to find the "last" one.  The code sample finds the highest integer resource ID within a range.  What if the last bitmap has a name rather than an integer resource ID?

Comment: @Adrian McCarthy In my case it wont but as Remy Lebeau suggested using EnumResourceNames() it will search for both. @ WhozCraig using FindResource() instead of LoadBitmap increases the load time by about 50%. I am going to write a function with EnumResourceNames() to see if I can increase the load time even more.

Answer (score 7):

Of course there is a more efficient way than just trying all possible resource ID values.

There are API functions specifically for enumerating resources in a loaded PE module. Look at [`EnumResourceNames()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648037.aspx) and [`EnumResouceNamesEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648038.aspx).

See [Enumerating Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648005.aspx) on MSDN for more info.

Comment: For some reason I can't get EnumResourceNames() to work with bitmap resources `if(EnumResourceNames(module, RT_BITMAP, (ENUMRESNAMEPROC)EnumNamesFunc, 0))` fails but if I change RT_BITMAP to RT_RCDATA or any other resource types it finds those resources perfectly fine. I'm not to impressed with the documentation at MSDN!